# 'ip addr' in SSH session, private and public address

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, ip, tcp

Execute the 'ip addr' command. As it happens, the instance only displays
private address, and I managed to get there using my public address?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you need to get public address :

```
curl -s https://ipv4.icanhazip.com/
```

or

```
curl -s https://ipv6.icanhazip.com/
```

You can ssh with any of dns or ip (public or private), the way you logon will never change the output of

```
ip addr
```

And you have only private address in your outputs :

```
$ for ip in 172.31.37.194/20 172.17.0.1/16 192.168.65.128/24; do
    ipcalc "$ip" | awk '/^Hosts\/Net:/{$1=$2="";print}'
done
```

### Output :

```
  Class B, Private Internet
  Class B, Private Internet
  Class C, Private Internet
```

### Explanations :

- you have different ip because it's 2 different linux instances
- you can have a public address only if you have no router/nor nat enabled behind an ISP box

Comment: okay thanks, but i'm also wondering why i could access to the private adress using my public adress?

Comment: Add context/output, dunno what you mean

Comment: https://ibb.co/eK2YSn , first session without SSH, second with SSH, why i see only private addres without public?

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output **in your original POST**](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: added comments in my post

Comment: Ok, so when im type "ip add" without SSH it shows me both public and private ip, but when when i type this command while connected via SSH it shows only private addres. Why is it happen?

Comment: NO there's only private ips

Comment: Okey, so it means that command "ip addr" always show ONLY private adress yes?

Comment: check edited post. You can have a public address only if you have no router/nor NAT/router enabled behind an ISP box

Comment: Okay, now all is clear for me, thank you so much

Comment: @Tomusz: Your two invocations of `ip addr` were not running inside the same instance of Linux, that's why the results are different.